# Visual Studio Work Mail Merge

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a function that creates a PDF File from a .csv file and a Word Document Template file.

The code has been working as expected for a number of weeks, however it is now throwing an exception.

```
Public Shared Function CreateDigitalCert(ByVal Certfile As String, ByVal PDFFileName As String, ByVal MergeFile As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        appWord.Application.Visible = False
        Dim docWord = appWord.Documents.Add(Template:=Certfile)
        docWord = appWord.Documents.Add(Template:=Certfile)
        docWord.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(MergeFile, False)
        docWord.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
        appWord.Visible = False
        appWord.activedocument.SaveAs2(PDFFileName, 17)

        appWord.Documents.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        appWord.Quit

        docWord = Nothing
        appWord = Nothing

        If System.IO.File.Exists(PDFFileName) = True Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If


        'Catch ex As Exception
        '    MessageBox.Show("Class. Create Digital Cert:  " & ex.Message)

    Finally


    End Try
End Function
```

The line `appWord.activedocument.SaveAs2(PDFFileName, 17)` is throwing this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Command failed

The variables are all populated and look OK. Any ideas what might be causing this?

**Edit**
I have tried restarting the PC.
`appWord.activedocument.SaveAs2(PDFFileName)`
`appWord.Activeocument.SaveAs2(PDFFileName)` 
`appWord.Activeocument.SaveAs2(FileName:=PDFFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF)`

Comment: What version of Microsoft Word do you have installed on the PC?

Comment: Office version  2016

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you use `ExportAsFixedFormat` instead of `SaveAs2`?

Comment: I tried the `ExportAsFixedFormat` is actually gave me an error message saying the Directory Path was not valid. I subsequently found that the function that creates the student directory was not returning a correctly formatted file path.

Comment: Gotta love it.  Machines do exactly what they are told to do.